# How to make the "rolling" effect in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I find that Resolution Randomizer (http://resolutionrandomizer.pop.us/ecard.aspx) is quite interesting. It has a rolling effect when you click the "Randomize" button.

I'm really new to Silverlight and I wonder how it is implemented. I'd like to add some similar effect to my project. Anyone has some scripts I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Nikhil Kothari's SilverlightFX project which provides some very powerful effect and transition declarations. As far as getting the rolling effect, you probably want to create a ContentControl containing the entire roller visual, and use FX's Move animation with an easing effect that slows down as it reaches the end of the animation. The Move animation would move the entire visual along the viewport.

[Nikhil's article explaining FX effects and transitions](http://www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-Effects-Transitions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Nikhil's site is down. Just letting all and sundry know. You can access the stuff using google's cache link tho: 
http://74.125.113.132/search?q=cache:ssbXtQS7bEUJ:www.nikhilk.net/Silverlight-Effects-In-Depth.aspx+SilverlightFX&hl=en&ct=clnk&cd=3&gl=tt&client=firefox-a